# Wordpress Sidebar showing in inspect on chrome but not on phone

Tags: php, css, wordpress, sidebar

I ran in to an issue. 
I've made a custom sidebar for a website. this includes a search, a category list and a pricing option.

[image: on chrome!]

As you can see up here, it shows it perfectly when inspecting on google chrome. 
But when I open the same page on my phone, it does not show up anymore.

This sidebar is supposed to be shown by using the following custom css :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    #sidebar {
           position: absolute !important;
           top: -9999px !important;
           left: -9999px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) {
    #sidebar-3 {
        display:block;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #woocommerce_product_search_widget-8 {
           position: absolute !important;
           top: -9999px !important;
           left: -9999px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #woocommerce_price_filter-10 {
           position: absolute !important;
           top: -9999px !important;
           left: -9999px !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
    #woocommerce_product_categories-4 {
           position: absolute !important;
           top: -9999px !important;
           left: -9999px !important;
    }
}
```

Which basically makes sure that on the desktop it has the sidebar on the left (sidebar). Which it hides on phones/tablets and such. And on phone it has the sidebar-3 on the top which is hidden on desktop. 
As you can see I even tried to do it by showing sidebar-3 by adding display:block. Sadly to no avail.

I'm using the same code on two other website's, where they work perfectly.

**Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?**